# Eclipse closes all shells when one is closed

Tags: eclipse, shell, window

I've a project which is a randomizer. The randomizer gives a random number (of course) which is used to call a random game.

For now, I only have one game.

When I run the randomizer to get the game, everything works and it loads the game flawlessly.

But, when I close the window which was created for the random game, it also closes the parent window which gives the user access to the randomizer.

I am not sure as to why this is happening.

I tried refactoring the name of my shell as well as my display, wondering if this closing was occurring because they shared names, but that didn't fix anything.

I'm not sure why this is happening or what code would prevent this from happening.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Nathan

Comment: You are going to have to show us some code.

Comment: You know, I actually got this figured out. The second application which is launched uses JFrames. Inside of the Window code the following was implemented `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` The name of the JFrame is of course frame. This function is what ended up closing all windows. Unimplementable this method fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was a JFrame invoking `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`. This was forcing all windows closed. Turning this off fixed the issue.