# ClassCastException in Eclipse Cloudio snippet

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classcastexception, eclipse-gef

I'm trying to use [Cloudio](https://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/GEF4/Cloudio) to generate wordclouds in an Eclipse plugin. To get started I try to make [this snippet](https://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/GEF4/Cloudio#TagCloud.2C_Word) work.

I copy/pasted it 1:1, only changing the display initialization to

```
final Display display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
```

because my plugin also creates a display.
(I also tried `final Display display = Display.getCurrent();` without a difference).

Now the wordcloud opens,  but it throws this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor cannot be cast to org.eclipse.gef4.cloudio.internal.ui.view.TagCloudView
```

coming from this line from the snippet: `if (!display.readAndDispatch())`.

Well, as the wordcloud still displays, the error is not too much of a problem for me. But one thing that happens is that when I close the wordcloud, the whole Eclipse IDE started from my plugin gets closed. I found [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707413/eclipse-closes-all-shells-when-one-is-closed) regarding this issue, and tried both solutions explained there (renaming shell and changing/removing `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`), without any effect. So I guess this error may be connected to the ClassCastException?

Edit: I've tried the same with the other snippet provided on the Cloudio site, with exactly the same result.

Edit: This is the original snippet I've posted the link to in the beginning (as I said I've replaced the initialization of the display):

```
   public static void main(String [] args) {
  final Display display = new Display();
  final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
  TagCloud cloud = new TagCloud(shell, SWT.NONE);

  // Generate some dummy words - color, weight and fontdata must
  // always be defined.
  List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
  Word w = new Word("Hello");
  w.setColor(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_CYAN));
  w.weight = 1;
  w.setFontData(cloud.getFont().getFontData().clone());
  words.add(w);
  w = new Word("Cloudio");
  w.setColor(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));
  w.setFontData(cloud.getFont().getFontData().clone());
  w.weight = 0.5;
  w.angle = -45;
  words.add(w);

  shell.setBounds(50,50, 300, 300);
  cloud.setBounds(0,0, shell.getBounds().width, shell.getBounds().height);

  // Assign the list of words to the cloud:
  cloud.setWords(words, null);
  shell.open();
  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```

Edit: I've solved the problem of closing the shell causing closing the whole IDE by overwriting the Close-event with setting the shell invisible:

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            shell.setVisible(false);
        }
      });
```

Edit: [Here is everything the console outputs when I open the wordcloud.](http://pastebin.com/xuHmBySu) It's this a few times:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-01-10 14:47:42.403
!MESSAGE Internal plug-in action delegate error on creation.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor cannot be cast to org.eclipse.gef4.cloudio.internal.ui.view.TagCloudView
    at org.eclipse.gef4.cloudio.internal.ui.actions.AbstractTagCloudAction.init(AbstractTagCloudAction.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.initDelegate(WWinPluginAction.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.createDelegate(PluginAction.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.refreshActionList(WWinPluginAction.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.run(AbstractUIPlugin.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: Can you post some more code to better understand the issue?

Comment: Hi, I've posted the link to the code, but I'll just edit it into the question.

Comment: please post full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: I edited it in. Please also note my edits which state that the problem which I thought was caused by this error wasn't in fact, and I do not know if this error causes any fact as everything works as I would expect it to.